# Covariant derivative property

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electromagnetism, field-theory, dirac-equation, dirac-matrices

I am trying to demonstrate this propertie
$$
\not{D}^2=  \mathcal{D}^\mu \mathcal{D}_\mu-\frac{i}{4}\left[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\right] F_{\mu \nu}
$$
where $\not{}~$ is the Feynmann slash, and $D_\mu = \partial_\mu-iA_\mu$. I tried to do the calculation:
$$
\not{D}^2=  (\gamma^\mu D_\mu) (\gamma_\nu D^\nu) = (\gamma^\mu \gamma_\nu \partial_\nu \partial^\nu - \gamma^\mu \gamma_\nu A_\mu A^nu -i (\partial_\mu A^\nu -A_\mu \partial^\nu))
$$
But I've gotten stuck at that point, it doesn't seem too much like the result I should have obtained! I would appreciate some help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

\begin{align}
\not{\!\!D}^2 &= \gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu D_\mu D_\nu \\
&= \frac{1}{2} \{ \gamma^\mu ,  \gamma^\nu \}D_\mu D_\nu +  \frac{1}{2} [ \gamma^\mu ,  \gamma^\nu ] D_\mu D_\nu \\
&=  \eta^{\mu\nu} D_\mu D_\nu +  \frac{1}{4} [ \gamma^\mu ,  \gamma^\nu ] [ D_\mu , D_\nu ]
\end{align}
We next have
\begin{align}
[ D_\mu , D_\nu ] &= ( \partial_\mu - i A_\mu ) ( \partial_\nu - i A_\nu ) - \mu \leftrightarrow\nu \\
&=   \partial_\mu \partial_\nu - i [  \partial_\mu A_\nu +  A_\nu \partial_\mu  ]  - i A_\mu   \partial_\nu - A_\mu   A_\nu  - \mu \leftrightarrow\nu \\
&= - i F_{\mu\nu}.
\end{align}
Thus,
\begin{align}
\not{\!\!D}^2 &= D^2 - \frac{i}{4} [ \gamma^\mu ,  \gamma^\nu ] F_{\mu\nu} 
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you! I small doubt: why $\frac{1}{2}\left[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\right] D_\mu D_\nu = \frac{1}{4}\left[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu\right]\left[D_\mu, D_\nu\right]$?

Comment: $[\gamma^\mu, \gamma^\nu]$ is antisymmetric in $\mu\leftrightarrow\nu$ so we can replace $D_\mu D_\nu \to \frac{1}{2} ( D_\mu D_\nu - D_\nu D_\mu ) = \frac{1}{2} [ D_\mu , D_\nu ] $.